# How is Visual Studio performance linked to enable/disable network connection?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

When i disable the network in ***Control Panel -> Network and Internet ->Network Connections*** i experience very good performance from visual studio. When i enable it, performance is very slow. I have checked this for building, debugging, user interface and everything.

Why do you think this is happening and how can i get the same performance by not disabling the network.

Comment: If you are on a company network, your user profile might be stored on a network connection.

Comment: I am on the company network. My userprofile is stored in my local drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue , Visual studio was running like a cheetah only when the cable is unplugged , ... I did the following and it did the job

I switched my workingspace from network storage to local hard drive

unchecked Updates in Tools->Options->Enviroment and updates

It can also come from TFS running ...